# How to get generic type from one class to another c#

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to pass the generic type from one class to other class generic property.

For example:

**Assembly Logger**

```
  namespace Logger
    {
        public class GenericLoger<T>
        {
            T _genericLog;
            LogManager _logManager;
            public GenericLoger(string logName)
            {
                _logManager = new LogManager(logName);

                //Assigning the generic type to Log.GenerciLog, this is how I am 
                  expecting or by some other possible way?.
                Log.GenerciLog = _genericLog;
            }
            public static Write(string description)
            {
                _logManager.write(description);
            }
        }

        public static class Log
        {
            LogManager _logManager;
            static Log()
            {
                _logManager = new LogManager();
            }
            public static Write(string description)
            {
                _logManager.write(description);
            }
            //The generic type supplied in GenericLoger need to pass here,
            //like this or by some other possible way?
            public static T GenerciLog { get; internal set; } 
//T is unrecognized here as type is available in GenericLoger 
//I want to pass here from GenericLoger
        }
   }
```

**Assembly Main Caller of Logger**

```
    using Logger;
    namespace DataProcessor
{
    internal class SpecialLogger
    {
        private static Lazy<GenericLog<SpecialLogger>> _passed;
        public static GenericLog<SpecialLogger> Passed
        {
            get
            {
                if (_passed == null)
                {
                    _passed = new Lazy<GenericLog<SpecialLogger>>(() => new GenericLog<SpecialLogger>("Passed"), true);
                }
                return _passed.Value;
            }
        }

        private static Lazy<GenericLog<SpecialLogger>> _failed;
        public static GenericLog<SpecialLogger> Failed
        {
            get
            {
                if (_failed == null)
                {
                    _failed = new Lazy<GenericLog<SpecialLogger>>(() => new GenericLog<SpecialLogger>("Failed"), true);
                }
                return _failed.Value;
            }
        }

    }

    internal class Processor
    {
        public void ProcessRate()
        {
            var trans = dataManager.GetData();
            //Will write the log in "Log.txt" file
            Log.write(trans.Count + " transaction found");
            foreach (var item in trans)
            {
                try
                {
                    //transaction process code here

                    //This will write the text in "Passed.txt" file. 'Passed' property I want to access like this
                    Log.GenerciLog.Passed.Write(item);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                     //This will write the text in "Failed.txt" file. 'Failed' property I want to access like this
                    Log.GenerciLog.Failed.Write(item);
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: no, also statics are bad in your case ... just use DI and pass interface like `interface ILogger { WriteFailed(...); WritePassed(...) }`

Comment: `Log` is static. You are saying that sometimes you want `Log.GenerciLog` to be declared with one type, and sometimes with another. Say you have one `GenericLoger<String>` and one `GenericLoger<int>`. T is int in one case and String in the other. But you can only declare `Log.GenerciLog` once, with one type. You can declare `Log.GenerciLog` as `object` if you want to be able to assign any random thing to it.

Comment: for logging have you considered using something like log4net?  available through nuget.  No point reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: In .NET you don't have a way for automatic type inference for use case like yours, also there is no automatic type substitution.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for

Your method definition should look like this

```
public static T GenerciLog<T> { get; internal set; }
```

and this is how to call it

```
try
{
    //transaction process code here

    //This will write the text in "Passed.txt" file. 'Passed' method I want to access like this
    Log.GenerciLog<SpecialLogger>.Passed.Write(item);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     //This will write the text in "Failed.txt" file. 'Failed' method I want to access like this
    Log.GenerciLog<SpecialLogger>.Failed.Write(item);
}
```

Comment: thanks @vasil, but I don't want to pass type every time that I am trying to achieve, actual I can do this without implementing generics and just by calling like this in caller SpecialLogger.Failed.Write('some value'); but I am trying to give only one entry point to developers to use logger by object Log. -> all respective log options

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple log class.  There is a lot more you could do with this sort of thing.  Its all provided by log4net which I'd recommend using rather than trying to write your own logger.  But the below is a start of how I'd implement a simple logger.  It allows you to log to several different things at once.  I appreciate the below doesn't answer exactly what you want but its an indication of how to start and you can adapt it to suit your needs.

```
public static class Logger
{
    private static List<ILogger> _loggers = new List<ILogger>();
    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        foreach (var logger in _loggers)
            logger.Write(message);
    }
    public static void AddLogger(ILogger logger)
    {
        _loggers.Add(logger);
    }
}

public interface ILogger
{
    void Write(string message);
}

public class SpecialLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Write(string message)
    {
        //special log code here eg
        Console.WriteLine(message);

    }
}
```

then somewhere do this

```
Logger.AddLogger(new SpecialLogger());
Logger.Log("A log message");
```

Comment: thanks @Tim, I know log4net is available for logging and we can use it but In my case our application is already implemented own logger that does other thing as well internally, there is no issue at all related to log here we just want to give one entry point to developers to use log only by object 'Log'. SpecialLogger is one of the additional functionality to create a new log file to log some specific data using same Log assembly if you look at the implementation of SpecialLogger in my sample code I shown generic only as a thought actual code does not have it.

Comment: in our code we are using logging like this Log.write('some data');  SpecialLogger.Passed.Write('some data'); SpecialLogger.Failed.Write('some data'), here you can see two entry points which I supposed to have only one like Log.GenericLog.Passed.Write('some data'), Log.GenericLog.Failed.Write('some data'), and also generic log can be extend with more log by increasing more property in SpecialLogger .